# Mock DateFormat in Junit and set Timezone

Tags: android, junit, mockito

I have a SimpleDateFormat used in my Extension function which I set TimeZone to GMT+6:00.

I want to **Mock Date format in my Unit Test and set the TimeZone to default**, BUT I keep getting Nullpointer exception every time I try to do this.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1770)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:943)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:936)
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:345)
    at com.s.internettime.MainPresenterTest.startDate_and_endDateTest(MainPresenterTest.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

How can I mock date format & set the set the locale? I have searched other DateFormat questions on Stackoverflow, they didn't solve my problem.

```
// Extension function
fun Date.format(dateformat: String): String {
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(dateformat, Locale.getDefault())
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+6:00"));
    return format.format(this)
}

    // presenter Test
    public class MainPresenterTest {

        private MainPresenter presenter;

        @InjectMocks
        DateFormat formatter;

        @Before
        public void before() {
            formatter = DateFormat.
          getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.getDefault());
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }

        @Test
        public void startDate_and_endDateTest() {
            MainListView view = mock(MainListView.class);

            presenter = new MainPresenter();
            presenter.attachView(view);

            // formatter.format throws Null pointer 
            Mockito.when(formatter.format(any(Date.class)))
                .thenReturn(TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());

            presenter.getStatus();

            verify(view).showStatus("2019-10-30", "2020-10-30");
        }
    }


// My Presenter class
class MainPresenter() : BasePresenter<MainListView>() {
    private val mainListView: MainListView? = null

    override fun attachView(mainListView: MainListView) {
        super.attachView(mainListView)
    }

    override fun detachView() {
        super.detachView()
    }

    fun getStatus() {
        // parse date

        val start = Date(2019 - 1900, 10, 30).format("yyyy-dd-MM")
        val end = Date(2020 - 1900, 10, 30).format("yyyy-dd-MM")

        mvpView?.showStatus(start, end)
    }
}
```

Comment: don't call actual methods with the mock objects. If you want to call the actual methods use `@InjectMocks`. Use `@Mock` when you want stub the methods instead of calling the actual method.

Comment: @komatiraju032 thanks, I changed to InjectMocks and I still get the Nullpointer exceptions

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: @truthsayer can you share the error

Comment: @komatiraju032 I have updated my code and It is the same error I keep getting.

Comment: @truthsayer If you want to stub the methods use `@Mock` only

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main problems with your code.

1- `formatter` variable is defined with the @Mock annotation but `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` is not called in the `before()` method.

2- `presenter` is not using the mocked `formatter` variable. So calling the `Mockito.when` function is actually helping nothing even though it is right.

After fixing these problems some more issues will come. However, these are the starting fix points.